# Tuple to have contains and not contains list C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like this:

```
var foundData = await DatabaseContext.Set<TableA>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => list.Contains(x.Code))
                .Select(x => x.Code)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

var notFoundData = await DatabaseContext.Set<TableA>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => !list.Contains(x.Code))
                .Select(x => x.Code)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

As this query hits the database twice and also, I don't want to retrieve all the records from the database and then filter. Is it possible to have a `List<tuple>` which does it in one query like

Suppose the database contains:

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

In reality, database contains millions of records. So does the list.

and list contains A,B,F

So found list will contain: A, B

And notFound will contain: F

So expected output is var (found, notfound) = ?

Comment: It isn't fully clear, which list of tuples are you expect. Could you please share expected input and output?

Comment: From the provided sample it seems that lists *foundData* and *notFoundData* together contain all records of the table *TableA*, isn't it?

Comment: Remove Where.  Then change From : .Select(x => x.Code)  To .Select(x => new { status =list.Contains(x.Code), code = x.Code})

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Gauravsa If provided code matches your production code and you want to get only list of codes then you can solve your problem using only one query. `foundData` must be calculated using LINQ-query. And `notFoundData` then can be calculated using next statement: `var notFoundData = list.Except(foundData)`. Does provided code match your production code and you need to get only list of codes?

Comment: "In reality, database contains millions of records. So does the list." Are you sure that Contains works if your list is millions of records? Or is list already on the database?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
var source = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var target = new List<string> { "A", "B", "F" };

var foundOrNot = target.Select(s => new { Value = s, Found = source.Contains(s) });

foreach(var entry in foundOrNot)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + entry.Value + "; Found: " + entry.Found.ToString());
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KL9yfK

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follow:

```
List<string> records = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
List<string> list = new List<string> {"A", "B", "F"};

var result = records
    .GroupBy(r => list.Contains(r))
    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key);

var (found, notfound) = (result.ContainsKey(true) ? result[true].Select(g => g) : new List<string>(), 
                         result.ContainsKey(false) ? result[false].Select(g => g) : new List<string>());
```

Comment: The query is to be executed by a database management system. Aggregate is not supported by LINQ to entities.

Comment: oh, you're right. I edited to tackle this subtlety.